# Sequelize PostgreSQL: Change Column type string to array of String

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using the Sequelize ORM with PostgreSQL.

I need to Change the type of a column from String to Array[String].

I used this migration Script

`up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.changeColumn('email','to', {
        type:Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT),
                allowNull: false
      });
  }`

> ERROR: column "to" cannot be cast automatically to type text[]

I tried the answer from **[this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2471)** link but It does not work for me

Please let me know If I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It was [issue with pg@7.0.2](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8043)

Downgrading to pg@6.4.1 fixes the issue.